# SSRS: How do I display a list of customers, from A - K then L to Z, without having two separate reports?

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I would like one report with a drop down menu, showing:

Customers A-K,
Customers L-Z
All Customers

I have an SQL table for customers, with the standard columns (Acc No., name, address, etc).
I would like this split by name as it takes a long time to bring the result of the entire table down. 
I would prefer this to be in one report. Is this possible? I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 with reporting services.

I have tried a few different methods with no luck, so I'm open to any suggestions!
Thanks for reading my question and thanks in advance if you can find the time to help!
Please feel free to ask any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table #alphab
( alphaname varchar(15));

insert into #alphab VALUES ('ANT')
insert into #alphab  values ('CAT')
insert into #alphab  values ('pAT')
insert into #alphab  values ('mAT')
insert into #alphab  values ('dAT')
insert into #alphab  values ('rAT')
insert into #alphab  values ('dAT')
insert into #alphab  values ('lAT')
insert into #alphab  values ('cAT')
insert into #alphab  values ('zAT')
insert into #alphab  values ('xAT')
insert into #alphab  values ('wAT')
insert into #alphab  values ('oAT')
insert into #alphab  values ('sAT')
insert into #alphab  values ('yAT')
insert into #alphab  values ('uAT')




select alphaname 
from #alphab
where alphaname LIKE
CASE 
    WHEN @alphabetorder = 1 THEN ('[A-K | a-k]%')
    WHEN @alphabetorder= 2 THEN  ('[L-Z | l-z]%')
END 
order by alphaname
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. The above query would show two lists, if running a query. Using this query in reporting services displays only one list. What I'm after is a report in SSRS which would, maybe as parameters, give you the option of running either report....

Comment: From the SSRS pass the parameter in which u send some value(say 0 if a-k needs to be displayed or 1 if l-k has to be displayed and NULL for all customers) In the procedure put a if statement to check the value passed in the parameter. In the ssrs report , i am sure u  might be using something like a link or a dropdown select as an option to select a-z or l-k or all costumers. In the parameter setting in the report , pass these values.

Comment: yeah it sounds like you know what your doing but unfortunately I dont! Sorry - can you break it down a bit? this is my first real report! woohoo!

Comment: no worries..  Firstly how is this a-k and l-z handled in the report. Are u giving an option for the users or how is it handled ...

Comment: exactly how do u want to handle this ?

Comment: Or u just want to query a to z first and display have a next button at the end to display the rest ?

Comment: at the moment my list in SSRS displays the entire table, all customers from 0 - z (some customers start with numbers!). I have a simple query: 'code' SELECT * FROM [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[AddressBook] where searchtype = 'C' order by AlphaName asc

Comment: So your problem its taking a lot of time to display the result ?

Comment: ok i would like the report to display a drop down menu (if poss?), with 3 options previously mentioned. once the user selects an option, ssrs would then run the relevant query - as in customers from a- k only. am i making sense? is this even possible?

Comment: Wel its better now.. So ur sollution.. Go to parameters  in the SSRS, say add parameters, A window opens -> in the GENERAL tab on left -> edit "Namebox" box on Right side and say "alphabetorder" ,edit "Prompt" box on Right side and say "Please select the customer ordering". Then  go to "Available Values" tab on left -> Select specify values button on Right side -> click on ADD -> in the label box give A-K -> And Values Box give 1 . Same way add two more for L-Z as 2 and all customers as 0. After adding the above 3 rows say ok.

Comment: Write a stored procedure , use this parameter in the procedure. ALTER PROCEDURE <procedure name>
( 
  @alphabetorder as INT
)

Comment: Wow. So now i have the drop down menu with the 3 options. when i choose a report, and click, 'View Report' it runs the report, but it is only running and showing customers A-K for all 3 options. Can you help further?!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40562/discussion-between-user2919277-and-lowtee)

Comment: ok, so its not working right! if you've had enough thats fine! if you feel you can spare a few more mins that would be great! Am i supposed to create the above stored procedure?

Comment: Wel i am running out for meeting.. befor that i would like to help u progress than leaving it through.. Wel. Its up to u to use the query directly or use the stored procedure. Before that let me know what is ur issue u r facing ? Have u used the CASE Statement which i have mentioned in my answer in ur query ? And also please check in the SSRS parameters , have you provided the values properly (for a-k the value as 1 and l-z the value as 2 and all customers the value as  0)